# Como pasar de un string a formato html?

Tags: html, python

me gustaría imprimir una cadena de texto en formato html, para que al nombrar a mensaje se diferenciasen las distintas cabeceras de html y no un string de caracteres (Lenguaje Python). Muchas gracias!

```
mensaje = """<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>Hola Mundo!</p></body>
</html>"""
```

Comment: ¿Quieres **imprimirlo** en consola o **mostrarlo** en una ventana gráfica?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo quieres mostrar en ventana gráfica, puedes usar una función como esta:

**Cödigo**

```
def add_tags(tag, frase):
    return "<%s>%s</%s>" % (tag, frase, tag)
print(add_tags('i', 'Mensaje')) # Devuelve <i>Mensaje</i>
print(add_tags('b', 'Este es un mensaje de prueba')) #Devuelve <b>Este es un mensaje de prueba</b>
```

**Explicación**
Esta función toma dos parámetros: *tag* y *frase*; tag es la etiqueta que deseas usar, como ves en la solución propuesta. frase es el contenido que quieres que vaya dentro de la etiqueta.